# Automating QGIS Raster Export -> Save as tool programmatically

Tags: pyqgis, gdal, qgis-3, export

I need to export a chunk out of an ArcGIS Server (Esri MapServer service) layer that is displayed in QGIS.
GDAL's clip by extent and clip by mask can't handle a web layer through the tool.
Using the atlas, I can't generate exact dimensions of pixels and pixel size due to DPI issues.

The Right click -> Export -> Save As method works perfectly, I'm trying to find a way to automate it using QGIS's own API in Python.